# Dixmier Conjecture

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, ring-theory

In algebra the Dixmier conjecture, asked by Jacques Dixmier in 1968, is the conjecture that any endomorphism of a Weyl algebra is an automorphism.

Which are some consequences of Dixmier conjecture which are different from Jacobian conjecture [ [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture) ] ?

Comment: The Jacobian conjecture is equivalent to the Dixmier conjecture.